# Validate ReactJS password confirmation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, passwords

I did a password comparison validation, but it is not working, could you help? I don't know if the form is different for react, but I didn't find something similar to do.

```
function validarSenha(){
    let senha = document.getElementsByName('senha').value;
    let senha2 = document.getElementsByName('senha2').value;
 
    if(senha!= senha2) {
        alert("Senhas diferentes!");
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```html
<div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="inputPassword" id="fieldRegister">Senha:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" minLength="6" maxLength="8"
           placeholder="(Máx 6 a 8 dígitos)" name="senha" required
           value={password}
           onChange={e=> setPassword(e.target.value)}
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputPassword" id="fieldRegister">Confirmar senha:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha2" id="inputPassword2" minLength="6" maxLength="8" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" required/>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container">
  <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 col-md-2" onClick={validarSenha()}>Cadastrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `onclick={validarSenha}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the possible reason is you are using getElementsByName, which says it will return values in the form of an array, while you need a specific elements's value, so always try to use **getElementById**, please find below correct answer

```js
function validarSenha(){
    let senha = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
    let senha2 = document.getElementById('inputPassword2').value;
 
    if(senha!= senha2) {
        alert("Senhas diferentes!");
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container">
                   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                       <label for="inputPassword" id="fieldRegister">Senha:</label>
                       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" minLength="6" maxLength="8" 
                            placeholder="(Máx 6 a 8 dígitos)" name="senha" required
                            value={password}
                            onChange={e=> setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputPassword" id="fieldRegister">Confirmar senha:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha2" id="inputPassword2" minLength="6" maxLength="8" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" required/>
                    </div>
                    
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container">
                    <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 col-md-2" onClick={validarSenha()}>Cadastrar</button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name ,you need use below method get value

```
document.getElementsByName('senha')[0].value;
```

and your onClick definition is wrong,you should pass a function declare instead of implement function

```
//no pass any value to function
onClick={validarSenha}
//pass the value to function
onClick={(e)=>{validarSenha(e.target.value)}}
```